# how to search image from project resources trough textbox and display in picture box

Tags: vb.net

i have a code but this doesn't work.. i tried searching in Google but nothing helps me.. can anyone help me here (sorry for the English) i'm a newbee.

```
   Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim currentMin As String = "_" & TextBox1.Text
        PictureBox1.Image = CType(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(currentMin), Image)

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Its Work for me

```
   PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(currentMin)
```

Comment: @user3242798 show the your image name and textbox.text?

Comment: @user3242798 case sensitive problem also occur in your image name? check the both (image name and textbox.Text)

Answer (score 0):

```
PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.<Name_of_res_file>.<Name_of_image_resource>
```